# Find delegated evt div's child - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I hope you can help me solve this problem.

I have an html structure like this:

```
<div id="main-randompart"> <!--This is added to the DOM as the web runs-->
    <div class="close">
        X
    </div>
    <img src="somesrc...">
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         let r = 'randomtext...'; //Here I have the randompart
         let s = '#main-' + r;             
         $("div").on("click", s, function (){
             let main = $(this);
             console.log(main); //returns the element
             console.log(main.find("img")); //returns nothing
             console.log(main.children()[1]); //returns something like: <img src="some_src..." 
         });
    });
</script>
```

I don't seem to be able to find the `<img>` without `children()[1]` which returns something that I believe it's text because I can't use `.attr()` with it. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried console.log($(main.children()[1])); ?

Comment: yep, it returns the same text and again I cant use .attr() with it. :(

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work pretty well:

The second parameter in jQuery *on* is for a child selector, so you might want to wrap your main in a container div, then you can get the attributes of the child you need.

Comment: verify the link

Comment: That's just a link to the homepage of JSFiddle. And regardless, you shouldn't use JSFiddle -- embed your answer in Stack Overflow using a snippet instead of posting to an external site.

Comment: That works because the HTML is added to the DOM later, not as soon as the user enters to a page.

Comment: Since you have a $(window).load, it implies that the content should be ready and the scripts should be executed when the page is loaded. Now, where are you trying to place your script?

Comment: That's why delegated events exist, the document.ready is to assure I can use jquery